# PostSharp and Blazor

Tags: blazor, postsharp

I'm looking at using PostSharp on a Blazor server project and was wondering if the limitation/restrictions outlined in this Postsharp blog (https://blog.postsharp.net/post/blazor-support-6.7.html) apply equally to both the client and server versions of Blazor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitations of using PostSharp with Blazor apply to Blazor WebAssembly only.

With the Blazor Server hosting model your app is a standard ASP.NET Core project. And the ASP.NET Core projects are supported by PostSharp without the limitations of WebAssembly.

Comment: Thanks. Verified that it does work fine in Blazor server.